# Prove that $G$ be a group under $\oplus$ that defined by $\bar{a} \oplus \bar{b} = \bar{a} \times_7 \bar{b} +_7 \bar{a} +_7 \bar{b}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, modular-arithmetic

In this problem, I stuck when find the inverse of each element in $G$. Please help me at least give a hint so that I can solve this problem clearly.

**Problem**

> Let $\mathbb{Z}_7$ be a group under $+_7$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*}$ be a group under $\times_7$ where $\mathbb{Z}_{7}^{*} = \lbrace \bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_7 \mid \bar{a} \neq \bar{0} \rbrace$. Let a nonempty set $G$ that defined as $G = \lbrace \bar{a} \in \mathbb{Z}_7 \mid \bar{a} \neq \bar{6} \rbrace$ and a binary operation $\oplus$ on $G$ that defined by $$\bar{a} \oplus \bar{b} = \bar{a} \times_7 \bar{b} +_7 \bar{a} +_7 \bar{b}$$ for all $\bar{a},\bar{b} \in \mathbb{Z}_7$. Prove that $G$ is a group under $\oplus$.

**My Solution.**

It's easy to show that $\oplus$ is an associative binary operation.

Now, $\bar{0} \in G$. Then, $\bar{0} \oplus \bar{a} = \bar{0} \times_7 \bar{a} +_7 \bar{0} +_7 \bar{a} = \overline{0+a} = \bar{a} = \bar{a} \oplus\bar{0}$. Thus, $\bar{0}$ be an identity element of $G$.

Next, we'll find the inverse. Let $\bar{a}, \bar{m} \in G$ where $\bar{m}$ be the inverse of $\bar{a}$. Then, $\bar{0} = \bar{m} \oplus \bar{a} \Rightarrow \bar{m} = -\frac{\bar{a}}{\bar{a}+1} \notin G$.

I get stuck. Please help at least give me some hint. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just write down the whole group table? There aren't too many elements. And then you should see what each element's inverse is.

Comment: ... and, when the group is larger, use the [extended Euclidean algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse#Extended_Euclidean_algorithm).

Comment: Alternatively, why do you think that that element isn't in $G$? Since you've excluded 6, that's a perfectly well-defined element of $G$.

Comment: Is $-\frac{\bar{a}}{\bar{a}+1} \in G$ ?

Comment: Since $G$ is including $\mathbb{Z_n}$

Comment: please can anyone help

Comment: @user113102 $\bar{m}$ is fraction meanwhile $G \subseteq \mathbb{Z}$ ?

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Associativity follows from that of multiplication & addition of integers.

It is clear that, indeed, $\bar{0}$ is the identity.

The Cayley table is then computed, with the help of $\color{blue}{\text{commutativity}}$ of multiplication & addition of integers (and hence of $\oplus$), as follows:

$$\begin{array}{c|cccccc}
\oplus & \bar{0} & \bar{1} & \bar{2} & \bar{3} & \bar{4} & \bar{5} \\
\hline
\bar{0} & \bar{0} & \bar{1} & \bar{2} & \bar{3} & \bar{4} & \bar{5} \\
\bar{1} & \color{blue}{\bar{1}} & \bar{3} & \bar{5} & \bar{0} & \bar{2} & \bar{4} \\
\bar{2} & \color{blue}{\bar{2}} & \color{blue}{\bar{5}} & \bar{1} & \bar{4} & \bar{0} & \bar{3} \\
\bar{3} & \color{blue}{\bar{3}} & \color{blue}{\bar{0}} & \color{blue}{\bar{4}} & \bar{1} & \bar{5} & \bar{2} \\
\bar{4} & \color{blue}{\bar{4}} & \color{blue}{\bar{2}} & \color{blue}{\bar{0}} & \color{blue}{\bar{5}} & \bar{3} & \bar{1} \\
\bar{5} & \color{blue}{\bar{5}} & \color{blue}{\bar{4}} & \color{blue}{\bar{3}} & \color{blue}{\bar{2}} & \color{blue}{\bar{1}} & \bar{0} 
\end{array},$$

from which one can deduce that

$$\begin{align}
\bar{1}^{-1}&=\bar{3},\\
\bar{2}^{-1}&=\bar{4},\\
\bar{3}^{-1}&=\bar{1},\\
\bar{4}^{-1}&=\bar{2},\,\text{ and}\\
\bar{5}^{-1}&=\bar{5}.
\end{align}$$

Closure is also implied by the table.

Thus $(G, \oplus)$ is a group.

Answer (score 4):

You are confusing the inverse in $\mathbb R$ and the inverse in $\mathbb Z_7^*$. To compare:

\begin{array}{c | c | c}
x & x^{-1}\, \text{in}\,\mathbb R & x^{-1}\, \text{in}\,\mathbb Z_7^* \\ \hline
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & 1/2 & 4 \\
3 & 1/3 & 5 \\
4 & 1/4 & 2 \\
5 & 1/5 & 3 \\
6 & 1/6 & 6
\end{array}

To be fair, elements of $\mathbb R$ and elements of $\mathbb Z_7^*$ are fundamentally different when it comes to algebra, so using the same symbols for them tends to mislead beginners. That's why on the introductory level, we use something like $\bar n$ to denote the equivalence class of $n\in\mathbb Z$ under some relation, here: $n\sim m \iff n-m\in 7\mathbb Z.$

Let me rewrite the above table using this notation:

\begin{align}
\bar 1 \times_7 \bar 1 = \bar 1 &\implies (\bar 1)^{-1} = \bar 1,\\
\bar 2 \times_7 \bar 4 = \bar 8 = \bar 1 &\implies (\bar 2)^{-1} = \bar 4, (\bar 4)^{-1} = \bar 2,\\
\bar 3 \times_7 \bar 5 = \overline {15} = \bar 1 &\implies (\bar 3)^{-1} = \bar 5, (\bar 5)^{-1} = \bar 3,\\
\bar 6 \times_7 \bar 6 = \overline {36} = \bar 1 &\implies (\bar 6)^{-1} = \bar 6.\\
\end{align}

I could have just guessed those, or better yet, I could have made the multiplication table for $\mathbb Z_7^*$:

\begin{array}{ c| c c c c c }
\times_7  & \bar  1 & \bar  2 & \bar  3 & \bar  4 & \bar  5 & \bar  6\\ \hline
\bar  1 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}} & \bar  2 & \bar  3 & \bar  4 & \bar  5 & \bar  6\\
\bar  2 & \bar  2 & \bar  4 & \bar  6 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}} & \bar  3 & \bar  5\\
\bar  3 & \bar  3 & \bar  6 & \bar  2 & \bar  5 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}} & \bar  4\\
\bar  4 & \bar  4 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}} & \bar  5 & \bar  2 & \bar  6 & \bar  3\\
\bar  5 & \bar  5 & \bar  3 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}} & \bar  6 & \bar  4 & \bar  2\\
\bar  6 & \bar  6 & \bar  5 & \bar  4 & \bar  3 & \bar  2 & \bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}}
\end{array}

As you can see, each row and column has precisely one $\bf{\color{red}{\bar  1}}$, so every element of $\mathbb Z_7^*$ has unique inverse.

To solve your problem, we have $G = \{\bar 0, \bar 1, \bar 2,\bar 3,\bar 4,\bar 5\}$. Now make a multiplication table like above, only use your operation $\oplus$ and look for $\bf{\color{blue}{\bar  0}}$.

---

I strongly encourage you to do the above. The alternative approach is less elementary.

Notice two things, $\bar a\oplus \bar b +_7 \bar 1 = (\bar a +_7 \bar 1)\times_7 (\bar b +_7 \bar 1)$ and if we add $\bar 1$ to all the elements of $G$, we get all the elements of $\mathbb Z_7^*$, i.e. $f\colon G\to \mathbb Z_7^*$, $f(\bar x) = \bar x +_7 \bar 1$ is a bijection with the  inverse $g\colon \mathbb Z_7^*\to G$, $g(\bar x) = \bar x -_7 \bar 1$.

These two things tell me that there is a strong relationship between $G$ and $\mathbb Z_7^*$. Furthermore

$$f(\bar a\oplus \bar b) = \bar a\oplus\bar b +_7 \bar 1 = (\bar a+_7\bar 1)\times_7(\bar b+_7\bar 1) = f(\bar a)\times_7 f(\bar b)$$ and similarly $$g(\bar a\times_7 \bar b) = g(\bar a)\oplus g(\bar b).$$

*(Compare this to your previous question and my answer there.)*

Now, I can easily prove that $G$ is a group (I will lose the $\bar\cdot$, $\times_7$ and $+_7$ notation, even though that is what is meant):

1. $(a\oplus b)\oplus c + 1 = (a\oplus b + 1)(c + 1) = (a+1)(b+1)(c+1) = \ldots =a\oplus(b\oplus c) + 1$
   $\implies (a\oplus b)\oplus c = a\oplus(b\oplus c),$
2. $a\oplus 0 + 1 = (a+1)(0 + 1) = a + 1 = (0+1)(a+1) = 0\oplus a + 1$
   $\implies a\oplus 0 = a = 0\oplus a,$

This is where it gets trickier:

\begin{align}
1\cdot 1 = 1 \implies (0+1)(0+1) = 1 &\implies 0\oplus 0 + 1 = 1 \implies 0\oplus 0  =0,\\
2\cdot 4 = 1 \implies (1+1)(3+1) = 1 &\implies 1\oplus 3 + 1 = 1 \implies 1\oplus 3 = 0,\\
3\cdot 5 = 1 \implies (2+1)(4+1) = 1 &\implies 2\oplus 4 + 1 = 1 \implies 2\oplus 4 = 0,\\
6\cdot 6 = 1 \implies (5+1)(5+1) = 1 &\implies 5\oplus 5 + 1 = 1 \implies 5\oplus 5 = 0.\\
\end{align}

So, there you have your inverses.

Essentially, we have established that $f$ and $g$ are group isomorphisms of $G$ and $\mathbb Z_7^*$, so they map inverses to inverses.